# XCode 4 downloads mac os x 10.6 core library?

Tags: xcode, ios

Well, I just got XCode 4, and at some point it starts downloading something called Mac OSX 10.6 core library. What is that, and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the documentation from Apple for Mac OS X, all of the class references, etc.  With it, you can look up different information about every class that Apple offers you (like if you wanted to learn more about the methods in the NSString class).

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks. But I wonder why didn't they include it with XCode 4 in the first place =/

Comment: Well you can technically work without them, so I think they are just trying to save you an extra gig or so on the download

Answer (score 0):

You can manually download & extract all the Xcode 4 documentation, by getting the links & instructions here: http://learning2code.blogspot.com/2008/05/download-xcode-docsets-to-your-hard.html